# Selenium WebDriver tests sometimes doesn't find elements

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng

I am pretty new to all the Automated Testing thing and recently I have been having trouble with selenium because sometimes fails finding certain input fields / buttons.

I added explicit waits for every element in the page, so the test is supposed to wait for that element to appear on screen, but sometimes randomly fails to do so. I will attach the latest error thrown by selenium in a simple test.

This is one of the tests that I am trying to run and randomly fails:

```
    @Test
    public void createTaskTest(){
        generateTestEnvironmentSalesForceHomePage();
        this.home.clickTasksTab();
        generateTestEnvironmentTaskPage();
        this.taskspage.clickNewTask();
        generateTestEnvironmentNewTask();
        this.newtask.setDateField("12/30/2016");
        this.newtask.setCostField("1500");
        this.newtask.setType("Personal Appointment");
        this.newtask.setPaymentType("End of the day");
        this.newtask.setDoctor("House");
        this.newtask.submitTask();
        Assert.assertTrue(this.newtask.checkDetailsPage());
    }
```

Error thrown by selenium:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed:     waiting for visibility of element located by By.cssSelector:                                 span.dateOnlyInput>input (tried for 130 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
```

Here is the method to find the 'missing' date input:

```
public void setDateField(String date){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(this.driver,130);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span.dateOnlyInput>input")));
    this.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.dateOnlyInput>input")).sendKeys(date);
}
```

Comment: Selenium questions should be asked at [SQA StackExchange](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Ok i will move the question there

Comment: @TimothyCope, who told you that? :)

Comment: @SebastianHerrera When the test is running can you see this element on the browser? Any chance these element are inside an iframe?

Comment: @Grasshopper No, its a simple textfield inside a lot of divs forms and tables but there are no iframes

Comment: @SebastianHerrera When selenium is timing out can you see the element visible on the browser?

Comment: @Grasshopper Most of the time i can, but the weird part is that sometimes the test skips some instructions. For example, about 5 minutes ago skipped the 'clickNewTask();' instruction and just started looking for the textfield there without clicking the button first. Any idea?

Comment: Has the test EVER passed?

Comment: please add the relevant HTML code for the element